# Change .ts file in webpack build

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I wish to change a value in a class in a ts file during the build process. I have a webpack.common.js, which merges webpack.prod/dev.js
I wish to swith out a variable that exists in my .ts file depending on which file is being merged.
The class is shown below, where VALUE_TO_CHANGE is the value to be updated with a value I specify for each environment.
Is this possible ?

```
export class AppSettings {
    public static VALUE_TO_CHANGE = 'replace_this_from_webpack';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> The class is shown below, where VALUE_TO_CHANGE is the value to be updated with a value I specify for each environment. Is this possible ?

Yes. Use environment variables.

## More

- Build toggles https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/build-toggles.html